# How to loop a number so that the number iterates through every possible value?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I was doing Problem 9 in Project Euler when I ran into a problem. My program was taking way to long too run. More than half an hour. Here is my code.

```py
def Problem9():
    a = 1
    b = 1
    c = 1
    x = []
    while(a + b + c != 1000):
        a = a + 1
        for i in range(0,1000):
            c = 1000 - (a + b)
            if a < b < c:
                if (a*a) + (b*b) == (c*c):
                    x.append(a*b*c)
                    print(a*b*c)
            b = b + 1
    print(x)

Problem9()
```

This basically is supposed to find out all the Pythagorean triplets which add up to one thousand(link to problem so that you can understand it better: https://projecteuler.net/problem=9) Is there a problem in my code which I can fix or is my code fundamentally wrong?

Comment: The looping structure seems very unnatural and convoluted.  You should have two ordinary nested `for` loops, and set the third variable from the other two. Optimize the exit conditions to avoid unnecessary looping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know that the three numbers must add up to `1000`, and `a < b < c`, you take advantage of that fact to loop much more efficiently (and cleanly).

```
def Problem9():
    for a in range(1000):
        for b in range(a,1000):
            if a**2 + b**2 == (1000 - a - b)**2:
                return a*b*(1000 - a - b)
```

Here, you loop over `a` from 1 to 1,000. Since b must be greater than a, you then looper over b from a until 1,000. Then, since you know that `1000 = a + b + c`, then `c = 1000 - a - b`, and you can test you Pythagorean condition without any more looping.

Comment: If `b > a`, the second loop must start at `a+1`.

Answer (score 2):

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c, for > which a2 + b2 = c2.
>   There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.

This will work

```
def pythagorean_tiplet():
  a = 1
  while(a < 1000):
      b = a + 1 # note this, b is starting from a + 1, since b starting from 0 is useless and will only add to the running time.
      while (b < 1000):
        result = a**2 + b**2
        c = math.sqrt(result) 
        if (( a + b + c) == 1000 and (a < b < c)): #test for conditions
            return a * b * c
        b += 1
      a += 1


print(pythagorean_tiplet())
```

This
algorithm is definitely unsuitable for perimeters s > 1 000 000.
There is a faster algorithm that can be used to solve it. you can search for `parametrisation of Pythagorean triplets`

Answer (score 2):

You've the system

```
(*1) a + b + c = 1000
(*2) a² + b² = c²
```

If

```
a + b + c = 1000
```

then

```
a + b = 1000 - c
(a + b)² = (1000 - c)²
a² + 2ab + b² = 1000² - 2000c + c²
( a² + b² ) + 2ab = 1000² - 2000c + c²
```

but, by the (*2),  ( a² + b² ) = c², and then

```
c² + 2ab = 1000² - 2000c + c²
2ab = 1000² - 2000c
2000c = 1000² - 2ab
```

then

```
c = 500 - ab/(1000)
```

So, now, you've the new system:

```
(*3) a + b + 500 - ab/(1000) = 1000
(*4) c = 500 - ab/(1000)
```

Besides, **a**, **b**, and **c** are whole numbers, and `a<b<c`;
if `a>332`, **a** must be, at least, *333*, and then, 
**b** should be, at least, *334*, and then, **c** should be, at least, *335*; `333 + 334 + 335 = 1002`.

With more math, you can do this even easier.

---

```
def p():
    for a in range(1,333):
        for b in range(a+1,(1000-a)/2):
            if ( 1000*a + 1000*b + 500000 - a*b == 1000000 ):
                c=500-((a*b)/1000)
                print (a,b,c);print a*b*c
                return
p()
```

Result:

> time python Special_Pythagorean_triplet.py
>
> `(200, 375, 425)
>   31875000`
>
> *real*    **0m0.041s** *user* **0m0.036s** *sys*  **0m0.000s**

In the **if** statement:

```
if ( 1000*a + 1000*b + 500000 - a*b == 1000000 )
```

you could use:

```
if ( a + b + 500 - (a*b)/1000 == 1000 )
```

but, in this case, only whole numbers matters: 
with the first, you get around division and its rounding problems.

Comment: 8 space indentation? WHY?

Answer (score 1):

A better way is use itertools

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html

```
from itertools import product
def ff1():
    for r in product(range(1,1000),repeat=3):
        a,b,c=r
        if a+b+c==1000:
            if a<b<c:
                if a**2+b**2==c**2:
                    print(a,b,c)
                    print(a*b*c)

ff1()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is really awkward. The while condition itself it's somehow wrong, you would stop with the first 3 numbers that sum  1000, then exit. Another wrong thing is that B doesn't reset. You can do similar to how Ibukun suggested, but it is not the best way to do for this direct approach. You DON'T need to check if they sum 1000. It's way simpler:

1. Iterate A from 3 to 997
2. Iterate B from A+1 to 999-A
3. Do C = 1000 - A - B  (that's how you don't need to check the sum, you kinda already did that)
4. Check if they are triplet, when they are, you are done!

There are other great approaches you can check out once you enter the right answer, they are way more interesting